# Skinny guy would like to get bigger (of course bigger muscles) but how?

Tags: weight-gain

I'm 21 and I'm 178cm with 71 kg.
I would like to reach 80kg.

I went to gym first 1,5 moths ago and I go to gym 3 times a week for 1 hour. (1 or more)
I like in a university dorm so I can't eat a lot of meat and stuff what I would have to.

With what kind of dietary supplement can I get bigger?

In the first month I gained 2,5 kilograms. But of course, I want more.

How can I do it?

Comment: If you have a specific situation that differs from the original that this duplicates, this could be a separate question. But right now the question and answer are the same.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to reach exactly 80 kg or do you just generally want to get fitter and stronger? In other words: How do you know what your weight should be?

Comment: There is no such reason, I just want to get bigger muscles and get stronger and fitter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put there are no magic pills when it comes to gaining muscle mass, there are two important keys when gaining mass   Which is first your nutrition. Your nutrition should be tracked using apps such as myfitnesspal (available on iPhone & android) this will ensure your eating enough protein to grow in the first place the second and less important aspect is the actually training within the weight room believe it or not! Aslong as each week you are in some way, shape or form progressing by either upping the repetitions on a given weight. Increasing the weight or increasing the number of sets then you are good as gold.